# Difference between ‘English school’ and ‘school of English’

Tags: grammar, phrases

I'm a Spanish speaker and I need to know the difference between *School of English* and *English School*. Sometimes I see these phrases, and I don't know which one is the correct one.

Comment: Please provide some context - where have you seen the phrases? But "English of school" (note that "English" requires a capital 'E') does not sound very English!

Comment: There is “no such thing” as *English of school*. You may wish to check out [our sister site for English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com). It’s “for people who are learning or teaching English as a foreign language”, whereas we’re “for linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts”. It sounds more like you’re learning English as a foreign language, so would probably do better there than here.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  Are you asking about the difference between English as it is taught IN school, on the one hand, and how English is spoken by kids who ATTEND school, on the other hand?  If so, the former is called "formal" or "standard" English, and the latter is called "informal" or "colloquial" English.  An example of formal English:  "With whom do you want to attend the concert?"  Informal English:  "Who do ya wanna go to the concert with?"  Each sentence communicates the same idea, but the former is "proper" and the latter is "casual."

Comment: sorry, it was English school and school of English, I have problems with that sentences, because the first one doesn't have "of". I visited some websites for example: "London School of English" and the other one is "English Schools in London".

Comment: @rhetorician That’s still pretty formal compared with the more normal “Whoja wanna. . . ?” :)

Comment: @tchrist:  Agreed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"London School of English" vs "English Schools in London"

- The first one indicates a school in London whose subject matter is the English language, or in other words they teach the English language there
- The second one probably indicates schools in London in which classes are taught in the English language, or in other words they teach all their classes while using the English language (e.g. Mathematics, Biology, and Philosophy, etc).

It is however possible that an English school in London would teach English!  The first phrase is definitely a school that teaches English.  The second one is a little ambiguous.